# Interactive mode on Scala worksheet not working..Any reason for this odd behaviour?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ and for some reason eventhough the "Interactive" option is checked, I don't see any of the println's or any statements visible on the right pane. few lines were displayed. But not after first 20 or 25 lines.

Any suggestions please.

[image: InteractiveMode not working in IntelliJ]

Comment: Does the output still not show if you click on the green arrow to trigger a run?

Comment: nope. it is very werid

Comment: Have you tried to invalidate the cache: File -> Invalidate caches / Restart -> Invalidate and restart.